# How to Find the Greatest and lowest value in listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am new in c#,

I am using these to find the greatest and lowest value .

```
        int[] numbers = new[] { 1,2,3,4,5 };
        int min = numbers.Min();
        int max = numbers.Max();
```

I want to find the greatest and lowest value from list box by something like this

```
        int[] numbers = new[] { listbox1.items };
        int min = numbers.Min();
        int max = numbers.Max();
```

There would be great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
var numbers = listBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Select(obj => Convert.ToInt32(obj));
int min = numbers.Min();
int max = numbers.Max();
```

Comment: i am getting an error the error is Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: What are in your items? Please give me some examples.

Comment: what is the prob can u pls say me

Comment: Thanks its working but i cant vote you because i am not having reputations