# C# WPF : Find largest value with a button in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listbox, listboxitem

It may be a small thing, but I can't find the answer to it.

What I want is when you add some numbers into the ListBox, that when you press the "Largest Button" it will show the largest number from the list.

Here is the image how it looks like: [Image Link](https://postimg.org/image/y3jqc9ipf/)

This is the code.

```
    private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem newItem = new ListBoxItem();
        newItem.Content = addNumberTextBox.Text;
        numberListBox.Items.Add(newItem);
    }

    private void sumButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (ListBoxItem item in numberListBox.Items)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Content);
        }
        sumTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
    }

    private void largestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       ????
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Find the Greatest and lowest value in listbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963144/how-to-find-the-greatest-and-lowest-value-in-listbox)

Comment: Instead of explictly adding ListBoxItems with number strings as Content, you should bind your ListBox to an `ObservableCollection<int>` in a view model. The numerical operations (like Sum and Largest) should be implemented as methods in the view model that operate on the ObservableCollection. Search the web for MVVM.

Comment: Also take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void largestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          int largest= 0;
          foreach (ListBoxItem item in numberListBox.Items)
          {
               if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Content)>largest)
                  largest=Convert.ToInt32(item.Content);

          }
          largestTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(largest);
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq it's simple,

```
var items = numberListBox.Items.OfType<ListBoxItem>;
var numbers = items.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Content));
var largest = numbers.Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
int highestNum = 0;

foreach (ListBoxItem item in numberListBox.Items)
{
    if (item > highestNum)
    {
        highestNum = item;
    }
}

highestNumTextbox.text = highestNum;
```